# How to set BarBackgroundColor for all views?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I've got an MvvmCross Xamarin Forms application that I'm developing for iOS and Android.

I'm trying to set the

```
BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("F26C4F")
```

for all views (with NavigationPage) in one common place.  If i was using straight Xamarin Forms, I would perhaps have a base class inheriting from NavigationPage and then setup the stylings in the base class constructor.

However, I'm lost because with MvvmCross, a lot of the startup code is in the iOS project.  All I have in the Xamarin Forms project is:

```
public override void Initialize()
{
    CreatableTypes()
        .EndingWith("Service")
        .AsInterfaces()
        .RegisterAsLazySingleton();

    RegisterAppStart<FirstViewModel>();
}
```

in the App.cs class.

So, what's the best way of applying common styling (ideally  to both app builds) in an MvvmCross Xamarin Forms application?

It would be handy to have a code snippet please.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [UIAppearance API](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/introduction_to_the_appearance_api/) on iOS and [Styles](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) on Android to do this. Though it would be platform specific.

iOS:

```
UINavigationBar.Appearance.BarTintColor = UIColor.Blue;
```

Droid

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primary_white</item>
```

Comment: This is a link only answer, and is really bad for future use when the links are dead. Please include relevant parts from both links into your question.

Comment: Great - thanks for the help pnavk. Just what I needed